# Download all pubmed abstracts

Tags: web-scraping, pubmed

Does anyone know how I can easily download all of the pubmed article abstracts? I am working on a text mining project.

The closest one I can find can download one abstract at a time given an pmid, but that would be too slow for my purpose since I'd have to download them one at a time.

Comment: Did you eventually write a script for that? If so, can you please share? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can get ALL the data from NLM directly via FTP.

https://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/download/terms_and_conditions_pubmed.html

Download and work away without worrying about e-utils.

Comment: I think that page offers MEDLINE, which I believe is a (signifcant) subset of what pubmed offers.

Comment: I think the link is now https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/download/

Answer (score 5):

Searching for `"0000/01/01"[PDAT] : "3000/12/31"[PDAT]` should get you every article from the beginning of time.

Maybe the "sent to" function shown right-above the search results will let you download everything.

Alternatively, you can write a script and use the Entrez programming utility from the NCBI.

You can perform a search query using ESearch, which will return all PMID's.
Then you can use EFetch to return all data. It is explained in this book/manual:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/

Chapter 3 contains some example scripts which should get you started:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25498/#chapter3

You will get xml files containing the abstract and all other data.

25 million XML files...

Answer (score 2):

I would use [RESTful API provided by Europe PMC](http://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService#search). They allow to download 25 articles per query in json or xml format. Example queries for articles about malaria would look like:

- http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search/query=malaria&resulttype=core&page=1
- http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search/query=malaria&resulttype=core&page=2

You can use different format of search query, it depends what you really want to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021, you can access the corpus through simple API of Huggingface Datasets.

https://huggingface.co/datasets/pubmed

Answer (score 0):

I am aware this has gone a bit stale, but they have a process for your exact same use case - large scale mining projects.

You can get the data via a free licensing agreement - more information [here](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/leased.html).